# Destructing objects on stack returned from funciton

Tags: c++, valgrind

Is the following code really dangerous? doSmth returns object of vector, which should be copied from `cont`(`doSmth`) and then stored in a stack in the scope of function `test`. Thus, I believe that it will be desctructed only after returning from `test`.

```
struct MyData
{
  double m_i;
};

std::vector<MyData> doSmth()
{
  std::vector<MyData> cont(10);
  return cont;
}

void test()
{
  MyData& oneElement = doSmth()[0];
  std::cout << oneElement.m_i << std::endl;
}
```

Yet valgrind thinks differently:

```
Invalid read of size 8
<line 1 in test function oneElement>
Address 0x101281db8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 72 free'd
std::vector<BlockInfo, std::allocator<BlockInfo> >::~vector() (stl_vector.h:314)
<line 2 in test function>
```

Is it a problem in my logic or valgrind lies?

Comment: Why not just doing `std::vector<MyData> v = doSmth(); MyData& oneElement = v[0];`?

Comment: Here's a more visual example: http://ideone.com/pG1n0. As you can see, everything's gone before ending the function.

Comment: I couldn't find this place in the standard, so I'm now not 100% sure. And I don't understand why valgrind writes `Invalid read of size 8`

Comment: I found this in C++11 § 12.2: *4: There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a diﬀerent point than the end of the fullexpression. The ﬁrst context is when a default constructor is called to initialize an element of an array. If
the constructor has one or more default arguments, the destruction of every temporary created in a default
argument is sequenced before the construction of the next array element, if any.
5: The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary...*

Comment: @KirillLykov, it probably dislikes you reading `oneElement.m_i` on the second line of `test` (since `oneElement` is dangling at that point).

Comment: @chris And if you study the explication in the standard more thoroughly, you'll realize that what is really meant is when a temporary is used to initialize a reference.  Which isn't the case here; what initializes the reference is the reference returned by the `operator[]`.

Comment: @KirillLykov Because you're reading a double in deleted memory, and a double has the size 8.

Comment: @JamesKanze, The point I was making with that was the part that said "There are two contexts that are different." This implies that anything not falling into one of these two is destroyed at the end of the fullexpression. I cut off most of the second point because it was long, but I should've explained my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value is destroyed at the end of the full expression, i.e. at the first semicolon in the function `test`. At that point, `oneElement` becomes a dangling reference.

You can prolong the lifetime of the return value by binding it to a const reference:

```
void test()
{
    std::vector<MyData> const & r = doSmth();
    MyData const & oneElement = r[0];
    std::cout << oneElement.m_i << std::endl;
}
```

In the above case, the return value is destroyed at the end of the function.

Comment: -1, because the answer is wrong.  The const reference is **not** initialized with a temporary, so the rules for extending lifetime don't apply.

Comment: @JamesKanze Doesn't doSmth() return a temporary?

Comment: Yes.  And it's destructed at the end of the full expression.

Comment: C++11 § 12.2: 3 `Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.`

Comment: @JamesKanze, I respectfully disagree. `doSmth()` is a temporary which is bound to a const reference, thus extending its lifetime. Where is the error in my logic?

Comment: The answer looks correct to me. In the question's code, `MyData& oneElement = doSmth()[0];` the result of `doSmth()` is not being bound to a const reference. In the answer's code, it is (the variable name being `r`). Was @James looking at the wrong code?

Comment: @avakar Yes, I was looking at the wrong code.  Although why one would want to make `r` a reference here, instead of making it a value, I can't quite figure out.

Comment: @JamesKanze, none (unless the return values's type had neither a copy nor a move constructor -- that's not the case here). I was pointing out a case in which the temporary can outlive a full expression (lifetime of a temporary is what the OP was confused about).

Answer (score 2):

The code has undefined behavior.  The return value of `doSmth` is a
temporary, which is destructed at the end of the full expression.  You
call `operator[]` on it, which returns a reference to data inside the
temporary.  After the destruction of the temporary, the reference
dangles, and any use of it is undefined behavior.

Valgrind is right to complain.